# Select combobox intem after bounded with SQL Query in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following pair of combobox that are used for two inserts in two different access tables from a single form.

The problem I have is that I am not able to make anything else load the form is selected both in Name_OT and in Year the first value that contains corresponding combobox.

I think the solution is with:

```vb
Combobox1.Selected (0) = True 'First value
```

But the combobox goes blank, no text or anything appears.

[image]

Comment: You can set a`Default Value`property for controls.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with this

```
Cuadro_combinado79 = Cuadro_combinado79.ItemData(0)
Cuadro_combinado85 = Cuadro_combinado85.ItemData(0)
```